# Problemas para fazer Multithreading com C#

Tags: c#, kinect

Galera, estou com um problema para fazer multithreading em um sistema com Kinect que estou desenvolvendo para meu projeto de pesquisa.

Eu entendi que isso acontece porque estou tentando acessar de uma Thread B um recurso que está na Thread A, lançando assim a **System.InvalidOperationException**. A questão é: Como posso resolver isso? Realmente não tenho a menor ideia de como fazê-lo (é a primeira vez que estou trabalhando com mais de uma thread).

Desde já, obrigado.

Ah, se precisarem de mais algo do código, por favor, avisem! :D

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da próxima vez cole o código direto na pergunta, e não em uma imagem! Fica complicado corrigir o código, digitar o mesmo e até mesmo alterar ele se ele estiver em imagem :)

Comment: Obrigado Marciano! Na próxima não cometo esse erro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de acessar um objeto que pertença a outra `Thread` é por meio de um `Delegate`:

```c#
private delegate void translateObjectDelegate();

private void translateObject(){
    if (translate.InvokeRequired)
        {
            translateObjectDelegate delegateTO = new translateObjectDelegate(translateObject);
            this.Invoke(delegateTO, null);
        }
    else
        {
             //translate.OffsetX = ..........
             //aqui você continua o método normal
        }
}
```

Primeiro o método verifica se o objeto está acessível na `Thread` atual na linha `if (translate.InvokeRequired)`, caso o mesmo não esteja acessível, é instânciado um `Delegate` e o mesmo é invocado, disparando a execução do método novamente de forma que o objeto esteja acessível. Se o objeto estiver acessível desde o início, o método será executado normalmente.

Algumas fontes para leitura sobre `Delegate` e `Thread/Invoke`:

[Delegate MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e(v=vs.120).aspx)

[Control.Invoke MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zyzhdc6b(v=VS.110).aspx)

[Control.InvokeRequired MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!